Limit Approximation of a Square Wave for Positive Values of x (Converges Faster than Fourier Series)
I've scoured the internet for any proof of this but can't find anything and need some help.
Prove that:
$ \lim_{h\to\infty} 2\sum_{k=1}^{h}\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left(2k-1\right)x\right)}{2k-1} = \lim_{h\to\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{h}{\left(-x\right)!}\right), x\ge0$
Upon adjusting the value of h to greater and greater values, it becomes apparent that the approximation on the right obtains a square wave shape much faster than the Fourier Series, and, without having to take any sums at all, it's clear that this is a much better approximation, the only downside being that it only works on the right side of the y-axis.
Any help is appreciated, and please let me know of any mistakes I've made in formatting or in just general reasoning.

The Fourier series is always going to exhibit the Gibbs phenomenon, but there are solutions to help reduce it.

I'm not sure if it helps, but $$2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (\pi (2 k-1) x)}{2 k-1}=i \left(\coth^{-1}\left(e^{i \pi x}\right)-\tanh^{-1}\left(e^{i \pi x}\right)\right)$$ and $$2 \sum _{k=1}^h \frac{\sin (\pi  (2 k-1) x)}{2 k-1}=\frac{1}{2} i \left(-e^{-i \pi (2 h+1) x} \Phi\left(e^{-2 i \pi x},1,h+\frac{1}{2}\right)+e^{i \pi (2 h+1) x} \Phi\left(e^{2 i \pi x},1,h+\frac{1}{2}\right)-2 \tanh^{-1}\left(e^{i \pi x}\right)+2 \coth^{-1}\left(e^{i \pi x}\right)\right)$$ where $\Phi(z, s, a)$ is the Lerch transcendent.

Also
$$\underset{h\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{h}{(-x)!}\right)=\frac{\pi,  \Gamma (1-x)}{2, |\Gamma(1-x)|}.$$
